# Работа с циклом +mysqli

Tags: mysqli, while, php

Столкнулся с ошибкой и никак не могу исправить. Мне требуется: Вывести из базы данных данные по такому запросу SQL: `SELECT * FROM matches_players WHERE match_id='$id' AND team ='a' LIMIT 5`, далее я думал, что результат будет таков: выводится только та запись (ОДНА), которая подходит под эти критерии, то есть условия, но результат другой, выводится 1 запись столько раз сколько всех записей. PHP КОД ЦЕЛИКОМ:

```
 $team_a_players = mysqli_query ($connectDB, "SELECT * FROM `matches_players` WHERE `match_id`='$id' AND `team`='a' LIMIT 5");
        echo '<p>Team A: ';
        $check_ready = mysqli_query($connectDB, "SELECT * FROM `matches_players` WHERE `match_id`='$id' AND `team`='a' LIMIT 5");
        $row_ready = mysqli_fetch_array($check_ready);
        $img_rdy = '<img src="img/ready.png" style="width:16px; height:16px;">';
        //echo $row_ready['ready'];

        while($team_a = mysqli_fetch_array($team_a_players)){

            if($row_ready['ready'] == '1') {

                echo ' '.$img_rdy.$row_ready['player'];
                //echo $img_rdy. $team_a['player'].' ';
            }

            else {

                echo ''. $team_a['player'].' ';
            }
        }
```

Помогите решить проблему, сижу уже полтара часа и не могу найти ответ. Возможно тут все просто, но я уже просто устал, прошу помочь.

P.S: в бд и в таблице в целом все в порядке 100%

Comment: Данные принимаете в `$team_a`, а выводите `$row_ready`. Зачем вы вообще выдергиваете данные вне цикла?

Comment: Fike, вы правы, но ошибка ведь не в этом, я это исправлю. Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем 2 раза один запрос к БД посылать?

Comment: @fremail я же говорю, что исправлю, но это не решает проблему. Мне нужно что бы картинка была только у тех записей, которые прошли все условия в запросе sql.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, что значит не в этом?

> выводится 1 запись столько раз сколько всех записей. PHP КОД ЦЕЛИКОМ:

потому что все пять раз данные вытягиваются в `$team_a`, а выводится один и тот же `$row_ready`

отвечающие не такие дураки, %username%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас каламбур какой-то просто!
Поправьте, если я не верно понял задумку, но моя версия кода была бы слегка проще:

```
$team_a_players = mysqli_query ($connectDB, "SELECT * FROM `matches_players` WHERE `match_id`='$id' AND `team`='a' LIMIT 5");
echo '<p>Team A: ';
while( $row_ready = mysqli_fetch_array($team_a_players) )
   if($row_ready['ready'] == '1')
       echo ' <img src="img/ready.png" style="width:16px;height:16px;">'.$row_ready['player'];
   else
       echo $team_a['player'].' ';
echo '</p>';
```

Comment: @fremail, я вас понимаю, но нет. Я понимаю, что у меня там половина кода можно сделать легче и нужно, но дело не в этом, я это сделаю потом, когда решу главную проблему. Проблема заключается, в том что мне нужно вывести игроков(будем говорить так) по ready, то есть если в таблице matches_players у игрока, допустим, "Igrok123" значение ready равно 1, то возле его ника мы выводим эту картинку ready.png, а у остальных, у кого ready = 0 её не будет.

Comment: >если в таблице matches_players у игрока, допустим, "Igrok123" значение ready равно 1, то возле его ника мы выводим эту картинку ready.png, а у остальных, у кого ready = 0 её не будет.

Предложенный мною код так и делает.